# Nginx logs without year and seconds information

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I have Nginx as loadbalancer which is generating logs without year and second information in timestamp. One of those logs are

```
08-10 09:28 root         ERROR    Error connecting to CRS REST API : [Errno 111] Connection refused
Error connecting to CRS REST API : [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

The pattern for this is : 
`(?m)%{MONTHNUM:monthNum}\-%{MONTHDAY:monthDay}\s*%{HOUR:hour}:%{MINUTE:minute}\s*%{WORD}\s*%{LOGLEVEL_CUSTOM:severity}\s*%{GREEDYDATA:messagePayload}`

While I understand that year information can be done by Logstash with current year, which is fine with me as logs are not old and collected on daily basis, but as seconds part is important. I am not sure how to do that?
One additional thing, I am using [date](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html) filter to convert it to time stamp to be stored in Elasticsearch which is as follows:

```
mutate {
    add_field => { "timestamp" => "%{monthDay}%{monthNum} %{hour}:{minute}" }
}

date {
    match => ["timestamp","ddMM HH:mm", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "YYYY/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z", "ddMMYYYY HH:mm:ss", "ISO8601", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSSSSS", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"]
    locale => "en"
    timezone => "UTC"
    target => "@timestamp"
}
```

It is NOT parsing it correctly and time stamp is not same in Elasticsearch, not both date and time.
Any leads?

Answer (score 0):

The discussion can be found here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/nginx-logs-without-year-and-seconds-information/57780