# Extract a timestamp from a date without the year component

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

[This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38891821/nginx-logs-without-year-and-seconds-information) is related but skips the part interesting for me.

I'm using filebeat to read CA Service Desk Manager logs written in a custom format which I cannot change. A single log line looks something like this:

```
11/07 13:05:26.65 <hostname>     dbmonitor_nxd        9192 SIGNIFICANT  bpobject.c            2587 Stats: imp(0) lcl(0) rmt(1,1) rmtref(0,0) dbchg(0)
```

As you can see the date in the beginning has no year information.

I then use logstash to parse the date from the log line. I've got the extra pattern TIMESTAMP defined like this:

```
TIMESTAMP %{MONTHNUM}[/]%{MONTHDAY}%{SPACE}%{TIME}
```

And then in logstash.conf I have the following filter:

```
grok {
    patterns_dir => ["./patterns"]
    match => { "message" => [
            "%{TIMESTAMP:time_stamp}%{SPACE}%{WORD:server_name}%{SPACE}%{DAEMONNAME:object_name}%{SPACE}%{INT:object_id:int}%{SPACE}%{WORD:event_type}%{SPACE}%{USERNAME:object_file}%{SPACE}%{INT:object_line_number:int}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:log_message}"
        ]
    }
}
date{
    match => ["time_stamp", "MM/d HH:mm:ss.SS", "MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SS", "ISO8601"]
}
```

Currently I have to rely on the automatic timestamp as the time_stamp is indexed as text and I've been fine so far, but occasionally the time the log line was written on the server is not the same as the time it was pushed into ES. Around new year I fear I will run into trouble with this and how the year is deducted from the current time. My questions are:

1. Is it possible to parse a date field from the data given?
2. Is there a way to write some advanced logic for the date conversion?
3. As we're not past the new year yet, is there a way to manually check/ensure the automatic conversion is done correctly?

Comment: For 3, if you're on a linux machine, you might try with faketime (but I don't know if it works) or if you have a test machine exclusive for this test, which don't need to connect over a network, you can just change the local time.

Comment: For 2, you can use the ruby plugin filter, which can be used to execute ruby code for each event going through logstash

Comment: For 1, you're already parsing a date field from your information with the date filter.

Comment: @baudsp I know it's being parsed but it is indexed as a text field on ES. I don't know if it's set up like that by my colleague or if ES determined it's text because of failed parsing or something else.
I will try setting up a fake pipeline from a dummy file containing faked log lines from both sides of the new year and see how logstash pushes it out to console.